# Include S3 object user defined metadata in list reponse

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

Is there a way to get a S3 object user defined metadata by AmazonS3 listObjectsV2? The only way I see in order to fetch this metadata is after listObjectsV2 request make another getObjectMetadata or getObject request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a S3 object user defined metadata by AmazonS3 listObjectsV2?

No, this piece of information is not included in the listObjectsV2 response.

> The only way I see in order to fetch this metadata is after listObjectsV2 request make another getObjectMetadata or getObject request.

Yes, this is correct. The only way to get this is to make a separate getObjectMetadata request.